# How to set Mercurial upstream

Tags: mercurial, push, pull

I created local hg repository for new project: `hg init ; hg addremove`,
then I created empty upstream repo, and pushed first version there: `hg push https://remoterepo`.

Now, I want to set that `https://remoterepo` as default upstream, so I can just do hg push/pull without giving it.

I was surprised Google did not give me a straight answer with "set mercurial upstream", and I didn't find a direct answer here at SO either. So, for the benefit of all the people using SO as a howto, what's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do that by adding the upstream URL to `/project/.hg/hgrc` like this:

```
[paths]
default = ssh://test@bitbucket.com/repos/something
upstream = ssh://test@bitbucket.com/repos/something_else
```

and now `upstream` is an alias for repo `something_else` which you can then pull from or push to:

```
hg pull upstream
hg push upstream
```

---

[Reference](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#paths)

[hg help urls](http://www.selenic.com/hg/help/urls):

> URLs can all be stored in your
>   configuration file with path aliases
>   under the [paths] section like so:
>
> ```
>   [paths]
>   alias1 = URL1
>   alias2 = URL2
>   ...
> ```
>
> You can then use the alias for any
>   command that uses a URL (for example
>   `hg pull alias1` will be treated as
>   `hg pull URL1`).
>
> Two path aliases are special because
>   they are used as defaults when you do
>   not provide the URL to a command:
>
> 1. default
> 2. default-push

Comment: Adding just the `default = ...` did the trick for my specific case (using hg pull/push without any extra arguments), thanks.