# Mercurial, different default upstream and downstream path

Tags: mercurial, push, pull

How do you configure mercurial to use different default remote repos when pull-ing and push-ing (i.e. not specifying that repo's name / path)?

Example:

```
$ hg pull
pulling from https://pull.from.here

$ hg push
pushing to https://push.to.here
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found this on the StackOverflow yet ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12777906/1820666) is related, but not what I was looking for), so I answered my own quetion:

You can set a path named `default:pushurl`, as indicated by `hg help config.paths`

So, having a `.hg/hgrc` containing:

```
[paths]
default = https://pull.from.here
default:pushurl = https://push.to.here
```

yields:

```
$ hg pull
pulling from https://pull.from.here

$ hg push
pushing to https://push.to.here
```

Comment: It's a relatively new feature so not surprising it's not on SO.

Comment: `default-push` was the old spelling, and it is still supported.  It was mentioned in your link.

Comment: `hg help paths` or `hg help -c paths` (`hg help config`is a bit long) may help.

Comment: that's a new thing I learned. thanks :) (`hg help help` will help as well)